# location wtih regex for nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to handle `sitemap` with `django`. So I want to proxy all `sitemap.xml` and `sitemap-<somethings>.xml` to my `django` app.How should I write my location expression in `nginx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using the following:

```
location ~ /sitemap(-.*|).xml$ {
        //
}
```

This way everything should be proxied from `sitemap.xml` to `Django`